Measure area of a polygon on OpenStreetMap
How can we measure the area of a polygon on a OpenStreetMap map?
It can be either:

the area of a hand-drawn polygon,
the surface area (at ground level) of an existing building

It seems the standard OpenStreetMap viewer doesn't has this feature in the toolbar.
This is similar to Adding a ruler to the OpenStreetMap site? but about areas instead of distances.

what kind of polygon are you talking about ? a self-drawn ?

Example @Taras, the surface area at ground level of this random building: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/54989463

You need to be very careful doing any distance measurements with data displayed in Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) or WGS84 (EPSG:4326)., since neither is suitable to Cartersian measurement.

@Vince I'm looking for areas if < 1000 square meter, so the differences will probably be negligible.

Unless you plan to map the Equator, the differences will NOT be "negligible" -- 3857 error approaches infinity near the poles.

There are a few websites that do this
https://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-area-calculator-tool.htm
Uses OSM base maps.
Example:

This site does use ads to generate revenue to pay for the servers.

Thanks ! But I see two problems in the UI/UX: 1) you can't zoom on a building, the maximum zoom level is not enough (I think this is already present on OSM)  2) you cannot pan / move on the map, but only zoom.
Would you do another website that does not suffer from this problem ?

use the control on the left side to pan and zoom in out. The satellite basemap has more zoom levels.
